# How can I merge two Corel Draw files

Tags: print-design, corel-draw

I want to print PVC card on a Matica XID8100 retransfer printer

However, I'm facing two issues:

1. I have list of 60+ cards with the front side in one .CDR file and back side in a separate .CDR file. The printers requirement is that the back file needs to show next page of card. So now I need to merge to .CDR file except updating one by one.
2. When I print through the .CDR printer, it is not showing the proper result. It is giving spot in print but when I print it through a JPG the print is clean.

Comment: Are you talking about data merging?  I think Corel calls it "print merge".  There are tutorials online for that. Just search. Your second question seems like a tech support issue. Have you contacted the printer manufacturer?

Comment: What is a CDR Printer? Such thing does not exist. What is Spot in print? Do not use JPG as an output.

Comment: Actually I'm printing PVC Card trough Coreldraw by matica xid 8100 printer and printer is not properly printing trough coreldraw but when i print from jpeg file its print clean

Answer (score 1):

A relatively fast way to do it is:

1. Open the Front view.
2. Add a new page.
3. Import the back view. All pages in that second file will be created. (File > Import)
4. If the back view is the same file for all, duplicate the page X times. (right click on the page Duplicate)

Or you can prepare an auxiliary file by importing the same page over and over.
File1.cdr (one page) Import it and save as File2.cdr (2 pages) Import it and save it as FIle3.cdr (4 pages... 8, 16, 32)

5. Use the Page Sorter View to overlap the pages as needed.

Comment: not working i have tried actually i don't want to add back view one by one i have only one back view i want it replace automatically after all page at once